# aws greengass: Node.js: Error: Cannot find module 'aws-greengrass-core-sdk'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I am facing a weird issue. I am sure that my node_modules folder has "aws-greengrass-core-sdk" but error is still saying that it cannot find module. 
Actually any of the modules in node_modules folder are not accessible.

I have spent a lot of time to find some solution but could not get any help yet. 
I would really appreciate for any help.

Thanks
Regards
Ayyaz

Comment: Can you provide some sample source code and a screenshot of your lambda function in the AWS console showing the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

Download the node.js Greengrass Core SDK and unzip it.

Then copy

> ⁨aws_greengrass_core_sdk_js⁩/⁨sdk⁩/aws-greengrass-core-sdk

to

> /greengrass/ggc/packages/1.7.1/runtime/nodejs6.10/node_modules